# Setting minimum and maximum lenght for two different UITextfields

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I have two UITextfields.

- First UITextfield  - Minimum value = 1 and maximum value = not fixed
- Second UITextfield - Minimum value = 0 and maximum value = 99

I tried using the following :

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    bool kCheck = NO;
    if([textField isEqual:txtDiscount])
    {
    if(newLength>2)
    {
        kCheck = NO;
    }
        else
            kCheck = YES;
    }
    return kCheck;
}
```

But control does not fall in the  `if([textField isEqual:txtDiscount])` condition.

Comment: txtDiscount is not defined in your method.

Comment: I think some other textfield (other than txtDiscount) is calling your delegate....

Comment: I think you can use `Tag` to distinguish with different text fields.

Comment: @Trisha : I have mentioned clearly in my question that I have two textfield. This is where I need help.

Comment: why dont you use  if([textField.text isEqualToString:txtDiscount.text]) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because you're comparing two `UITextField` objects to each other, rather than the strings they contain. Calling `isEqual` is the correct idea, but you're calling it on the wrong things.

I think what you wanted to write was this:

```
if([textField.text isEqual:txtDiscount.text])
```

i.e. you need to pull out the text properties to compare to each other.

Comment: txtDiscount is a UITextfield.

Comment: String omparison worked. The only difference in your solution is that txtDiscount is UITextfield and not a string. Please edit your answer accordingly.